# How to select all the text in a table column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

## Select Table Column

---

### Question

*I am trying to select only one column. The table is split into to categories: `unselect` and `select`. I used css to only allow the `select` column cells to be shown as selected text. The selection works fantastic, but it will only select the cell in the selected column.*

**How will I select an entire column's TEXT without the other column's text being selected?**

---

### Code

```js
$('td#select').click(function() {
  if (document.selection) {
    var block = document.body.createTextRange();
    block.moveToElementText($(this)[0]);
    block.select();
  } else {
    var block = document.createRange();
    block.setStartBefore($(this)[0]);
    block.setEndAfter($(this)[0]);
    window.getSelection().addRange(block);
  }
});
```

```css
td#unselect {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
td#select {
  -webkit-user-select: all;
  -moz-user-select: all;
  -ms-user-select: all;
  -o-user-select: all;
  user-select: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="unselect">1</td>
    <td id="select">Alex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="unselect">2</td>
    <td id="select">Bob</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="unselect">3</td>
    <td id="select">Sally</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="unselect">4</td>
    <td id="select">Jim</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="unselect">5</td>
    <td id="select">Jack</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="unselect">6</td>
    <td id="select">Arthur</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HovyTech/ykcyguqz/)

Comment: IDs *should* be unique! Use `data-*` attributes or class instead.

Comment: Yes, but that won't help me to select 50 cells at once?

Comment: It would. If using classes, just use **. - class selector** `$('.select')...`

Comment: @isherwood How is this a duplicate when that one only colours the cells and this one selects the text of the cells?

Comment: Now I'm not sure whether you're asking for a class selector or a table cell column selector. Which is it?

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/ykcyguqz/6/

Comment: @isherwood I want to be able to click on the table's column and it must select each cell in that column's text. I'm doing it like this so that you wouldn't have to select the entire column.

Comment: @ShaunakD Your fiddle doesn't work for me in Chrome. Also, answers go down there.

Comment: @ShaunakD That doesn't work, because it doesn't select the entire column's text.

Comment: I was hoping it was. Would there be an alternative?

Comment: Here's a start, but it generates the error `Discontiguous selection is not supported.` in Chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/ykcyguqz/11/